# Does implicit casting negatively affect index usage?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT id FROM MyTable
WHERE eventCount > eventCutoff * eventFactor
```

`eventCount` and `eventCutoff` are defined as a smallint, and `eventFactor` as a float.

I have two questions: is there an implicit cast of `eventCount` to a float for the comparison? And if so, will this prevent me from effectively leveraging an index on `eventCount`?

Comment: Why is event factor a float? Are you going to require dozens of decimal places? I would suspect that be defined as a decimal with a much smaller scale and precision (and more predictable behavior, e.g. rounding).

Comment: That is not sargable anyway. You can create and index a computed column on `CASE WHEN eventCount > eventCutoff * eventFactor THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` to use an index.

Answer (score 5):

Such conversion often will occur, and they can often impact cardinality estimation (and hence can affect plan quality). It will depend though on data types, existing indexes, cardinality etc. For example this query might not be able to seek in any case, as SQL Server might be using a scan regardless.

You should be able to determine if this is an issue in your case by inspecting the execution plan - do you get a scan on `eventCount` if you first cast `eventFactor` to a `smallint`? What if you use a local `smallint` variable that would result in the same number of rows that would match the filter? We can't tell from here...